# Liquibase stopped working after moving from 3.6.3 to 3.8.7 or 3.10.2

Tags: powershell, db2, liquibase, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I was using liquibase 3.6.3 and everything worked fine but today I've moved to 3.10.2 and suddenly I can't run any database updates. The only thing which is in the log file I've pasted below.
We run on DB2 for IBM i.
We use power shell scripts and bat scripts and if we run them outside of the liquibase, everything works fine but when those scripts get called from liquibase after the upgrade, it hangs on the last line from below log.

````
liquibase.log exist.
Liquibase found.
10:42:16.338 [main] DEBUG l.integration.commandline.Main - Custom logging config found, not going to modify
10:42:16.373 [main] DEBUG l.r.ClassLoaderResourceAccessor - Opening jar:file:/C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/lib/liquibase/content/liquibase.jar!/liquibase.build.properties as liquibase.build.properties
10:42:16.378 [main] INFO  l.integration.commandline.Main - 
Starting Liquibase at Mon, 24 Aug 2020 10:42:16 CEST (version 3.10.2 #22 built at Mon Jul 27 04:21:02 UTC 2020)
10:42:16.392 [main] DEBUG l.r.ClassLoaderResourceAccessor - Opening jar:file:/C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/lib/liquibase/content/liquibase.jar!/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF as META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
10:42:16.393 [main] DEBUG l.r.ClassLoaderResourceAccessor - Opening jar:file:/C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/lib/liquibase/content/lib/commons-cli-1.4.jar!/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF as META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
10:42:16.393 [main] DEBUG l.r.ClassLoaderResourceAccessor - Opening jar:file:/C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/lib/liquibase/content/lib/h2-1.4.200.jar!/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF as META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
10:42:16.394 [main] DEBUG l.r.ClassLoaderResourceAccessor - Opening jar:file:/C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/lib/liquibase/content/lib/jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar!/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF as META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
10:42:16.394 [main] DEBUG l.r.ClassLoaderResourceAccessor - Opening jar:file:/C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/lib/liquibase/content/lib/jaxb-core-2.3.0.jar!/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF as META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
10:42:16.395 [main] DEBUG l.r.ClassLoaderResourceAccessor - Opening jar:file:/C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/lib/liquibase/content/lib/jaxb-impl-2.3.0.jar!/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF as META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
10:42:16.396 [main] DEBUG l.r.ClassLoaderResourceAccessor - Opening jar:file:/C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/lib/liquibase/content/lib/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar!/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF as META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
10:42:16.397 [main] DEBUG l.r.ClassLoaderResourceAccessor - Opening jar:file:/C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/lib/liquibase/content/lib/logback-core-1.2.3.jar!/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF as META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
10:42:16.397 [main] DEBUG l.r.ClassLoaderResourceAccessor - Opening jar:file:/C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/lib/liquibase/content/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar!/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF as META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
10:42:16.398 [main] DEBUG l.r.ClassLoaderResourceAccessor - Opening jar:file:/C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/lib/liquibase/content/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.28.jar!/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF as META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
10:42:16.398 [main] DEBUG l.r.ClassLoaderResourceAccessor - Opening jar:file:/C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/lib/liquibase/content/lib/snakeyaml-1.18.jar!/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF as META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
10:42:16.398 [main] DEBUG l.r.ClassLoaderResourceAccessor - Opening jar:file:/C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/lib/liquibase/content/lib/snakeyaml-1.24.jar!/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF as META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
10:42:16.403 [main] DEBUG l.servicelocator.ServiceLocator - ServiceLocator.findClasses for liquibase.license.LicenseService
10:42:16.403 [main] DEBUG l.servicelocator.ServiceLocator - ServiceLocator finding classes matching interface liquibase.license.LicenseService
10:42:16.403 [main] DEBUG l.s.DefaultPackageScanClassResolver - Searching for implementations of liquibase.license.LicenseService in packages: [liquibase.change, liquibase.command, liquibase.changelog, liquibase.database, liquibase.parser, liquibase.precondition, liquibase.datatype, liquibase.serializer, liquibase.sqlgenerator, liquibase.executor, liquibase.snapshot, liquibase.logging, liquibase.diff, liquibase.structure, liquibase.structurecompare, liquibase.lockservice, liquibase.sdk.database, liquibase.ext, liquibase.pro, com.datical.liquibase]```
````

Comment: Which Db2 driver and version is being used in the __working__ case, as compared to the __failing__ case?

Comment: We use jt400 but the version does not matter here as we run all those scripts outside liquibase just fine and jt400 is used in both cases.

IBM Toolbox for Java:
Open Source Software, JTOpen 9.5, codebase 5770-SS1 V7R3M0.00 built=20180111 @VB
Supports JDBC version 4.2
Toolbox driver version 11.5

Comment: If the same jt400 version is used by __both__ liquibase versions, then trace the jt400 behaviour in both cases and compare the output.

Comment: How can I trace jt400 behaviour in liquibase?  Also I can't see from the log that this is jt400 related problem.
Jt400 path is specified in the script so it is always the same:
powershell.exe -file ..\tools\runLiquibase.ps1 -changeLogFile main.json -driver com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver -classpath ..\tools\jt400\jt400.jar -url "jdbc:as400://%system%/%schema%;date format=iso;"  -username %user% -pass %pass% -contexts "%contexts%" -command "update -DCurrentLib=%schema%"

Comment: If your symptom is a hang, you need to determine what is hanging (which component). One way to do that is to compare appropriate traces of working and failing cases. To trace jt400, refer to docs , example https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/643289

Comment: Still, looking at debug log, it does not look like it is jt400 problem. I will try to trace it but log does not say anything about it.

Comment: I think I have found the cause:
liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor - Executing with the 'jdbc' executor
16:11:51.779 [main] INFO  liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor - SELECT fixpack_num FROM TABLE (sysproc.env_get_inst_info()) as INSTANCEINFO
16:11:51.997 [main] INFO  liquibase.database.core.DB2Database - Error getting fix pack number
liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Error executing SQL SELECT fixpack_num FROM TABLE (sysproc.env_get_inst_info()) as INSTANCEINFO: [SQL0204] ENV_GET_INST_INFO in SYSPROC type *N not found.
Looks like https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-3580

Comment: There should be a way for you to choose the dialect for Db2  (i.e. to choose between Db2-LUW,  Db2-for-i,  and Db2-for-Z ) as their catalogs differ, among other things.  Anyway, the liquibase should not hang, but instead show that error, so it appears broken. Missing test-cases or test-environments perhaps.

Comment: Do you have a valid liquibase license?  If it is hanging here " Searching for implementations of liquibase.license..." I would check that my liquibase license is valid and present in my liquibase.properties file, or remove it to use the Community OSS version.